# There already exists an implementation for service org.kie.api.internal.assembler.KieAssemblers with same priority 0

Tags: eclipse, junit, jbpm, bpmn

I am trying to test a Hello World example of BPMN on Eclipse. I have followed the section "24.1. jBPM Eclipse Plugin" on https://docs.jbpm.org/7.67.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single where I select to use a simple "Hello World" process and to include a JUnit test class that will be used to test the process.

However, I am facing an error when I am running the ProcessTest.java as a JUnit Test.

Here is the full error :

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.drools.dynamic.DynamicServiceRegistrySupplier.get(DynamicServiceRegistrySupplier.java:32)
    at org.drools.dynamic.DynamicServiceRegistrySupplier.get(DynamicServiceRegistrySupplier.java:23)
    at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceRegistry$Impl.getServiceRegistry(ServiceRegistry.java:90)
    at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceRegistry$ServiceRegistryHolder.<clinit>(ServiceRegistry.java:49)
    at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceRegistry.getInstance(ServiceRegistry.java:41)
    at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceRegistry.getService(ServiceRegistry.java:37)
    at org.kie.internal.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory$FactoryServiceHolder.<clinit>(KnowledgeBuilderFactory.java:39)
    at org.kie.internal.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder(KnowledgeBuilderFactory.java:52)
    at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.SimpleRuntimeEnvironment.<init>(SimpleRuntimeEnvironment.java:99)
    at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.SimpleRuntimeEnvironment.<init>(SimpleRuntimeEnvironment.java:93)
    at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.<init>(RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.kie.api.runtime.manager.RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder$Factory.<clinit>(RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.java:61)
    at org.jbpm.test.JbpmJUnitBaseTestCase.createRuntimeManager(JbpmJUnitBaseTestCase.java:351)
    at org.jbpm.test.JbpmJUnitBaseTestCase.createRuntimeManager(JbpmJUnitBaseTestCase.java:293)
    at org.jbpm.test.JbpmJUnitBaseTestCase.createRuntimeManager(JbpmJUnitBaseTestCase.java:275)
    at com.sample.ProcessTest.testProcess(ProcessTest.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to build kie service url = jar:file:/C:/Users/lucie/.m2/repository/org/kie/kie-internal/7.71.0.Final/kie-internal-7.71.0.Final.jar!/META-INF/kie/kie-internal/kie.conf
    at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.registerConfs(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:127)
    at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.lambda$getServices$1(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:105)
    at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Unknown Source)
    at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.getServices(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:103)
    at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceRegistry$Impl.<init>(ServiceRegistry.java:62)
    at org.drools.dynamic.DynamicServiceRegistrySupplier$LazyHolder.<clinit>(DynamicServiceRegistrySupplier.java:27)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There already exists an implementation for service org.kie.api.internal.assembler.KieAssemblers with same priority 0
    at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl$PriorityMap.put(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:244)
    at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.processKieService(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:146)
    at org.kie.api.internal.utils.ServiceDiscoveryImpl.registerConfs(ServiceDiscoveryImpl.java:123)
    ... 56 more
```

Here is my pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>msc</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  <build>
   <plugins>
   <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
   </plugins>
   </build>
   
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbpm-test</artifactId>
        <version>7.71.0.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbpm-runtime-manager</artifactId>
        <version>7.71.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-internal</artifactId>
        <version>7.71.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.27.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have tried to clear the Maven cache but the error is still here. I don't know how I could try to resolve it, so I was wondering if anyone has an idea ? Thanks a lot for the help !

Here is the ProcessTest.java :

```
package com.sample;

import org.jbpm.test.JbpmJUnitBaseTestCase;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;
import org.kie.api.runtime.manager.RuntimeEngine;
import org.kie.api.runtime.manager.RuntimeManager;
import org.kie.api.runtime.process.ProcessInstance;

/**
 * This is a sample file to test a process.
 */
public class ProcessTest extends JbpmJUnitBaseTestCase {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Test
    public void testProcess() {
        RuntimeManager manager = createRuntimeManager("sample.bpmn");
        RuntimeEngine engine = getRuntimeEngine(null);
        KieSession ksession = engine.getKieSession();
        
        ProcessInstance processInstance = ksession.startProcess("com.sample.bpmn.hello");
        // check whether the process instance has completed successfully
        assertProcessInstanceCompleted(processInstance.getId(), ksession);
        assertNodeTriggered(processInstance.getId(), "Hello");
        
        manager.disposeRuntimeEngine(engine);
        manager.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: could you please share the ProcessTest.java source as well. it seems you're trying to initialize a singleton again

Comment: this might help - https://groups.google.com/g/drools-usage/c/ogbqrOEYdls

Comment: Thank you so much ! This has helped me, I was having the same jar file (kie-internal) two times. So I deleted one and now the test is successful.